# how would i go about creating a base 10 to base 2 converter

Tags: logic, binary

I am trying to create a calculator in excel for use in Minecraft later and I was wondering if the was any way to create and how I would create a base 10 to base 2 converter with only logic gates. if you need the .xlsx file for reference I will put it in the comments.

Comment: https://github.com/TheRealDestroyer/Logic-Calculator-In-Excel/blob/main/Logic%20Playgroung.xlsx

Comment: So would the idea be to implement a calculator in Minecraft’s redstone, (that is, in NOR gates)? I think you should specify how you are planning to represent the decimal in the first place. Maybe you would have ten buttons that the user of the calculator would push? So ten separate wires? Or were you planning something different?

Comment: right now, I'm just trying to get a working prototype in excel. @Ryan1729